# How to set part of string bold?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I want to take a string from a cell and examine it for keywords. These keywords should then be marked Bold and the complete string should be returned with the Bold marked keywords. Here is an example:

```
=boldKeywords("I am an example text", "text")
```

Result: I am an example **text**.

The script works so far. I am just not possible to make the keywords bold. This should happen here: "//splitString[i] should be set bold". Here is the script:

```js
function boldKeywords(text, keywords) {
    
// Split the test and the keywords into an Array with single Strings
  var splitString = text.split(" ");
  var splitKeywords = keywords.toUpperCase().split(", ");
    
//Go through the array and compare each word to the keywords
  for(var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++){
      if(splitString[i].toUpperCase().localeCompare(splitKeywords[j]) == 0){
        //splitString[i] should be set bold
      }
    } 
  }
     
//Concatenate Array Sting to one String
  var retunString = "";
          
  for(var j = 0; j < splitString.length; j++) {
    retunString = retunString + " " + splitString[j];
  }

//return String
  return retunString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To make parts of a cell content bold, you need to use [RichText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newrichtextvalue)

As mentioned by Marios, you cannot use RichText in a custom formula, so you have to modify your set-up a bit.

for example, you can write your key word(s) into a free cell (e.g. `A1`) and create a [custom button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) to which you can assign the following script:

```js
function boldKeywords() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var text = cell.getValue();
  var keywords = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();  
  // Split the test and the keywords into an Array with single Strings
  var splitString = text.split(" ");
  var splitKeywords = keywords.toUpperCase().split(", ");
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
  value.setText(text);
  var position = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < splitKeywords.length; j++){
      if(splitString[i].toUpperCase().localeCompare(splitKeywords[j]) == 0){
        var start = text.indexOf(splitString[i], position)-1;
        var end = start + splitString[i].length+1;
        var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
        value.setTextStyle(start, end, bold);       
      }
    } 
    position += splitString[i].length+1;
  }  
  var values = value.build();
  cell.setRichTextValue(values);
}
```

This script will mark all the keywords bold for the cell that is being selected at the moment you press on the button.

[image]

Note that if you expect to encounter more than once in a cell, it is important to define `position` to correctly highlight all instances of a keyword as bold.

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately, custom functions can not return formatted data.

This issue has been reported already in the [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145501368). You can click on the star button to the top left of the page to increase the chances of this feature to be implemented by Google.

**Potential workarounds:**

- You can create a button/menu to execute a regular function that will be able to set the format and the value of the selected cell.
- You can use an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to set the format and the value of the cell when you edit that cell or when you click on a checkbox for example.
- You can set up a time-driven trigger to change the format of the cell when the cell hasn't been formatted properly.