# Dynamic hyperlink & Text in the same cell with a formula in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, concatenation

*Note: consider checking the edits first if you have a similar problem*

I have Link, Lable, Text and Formula as input
and the formula uses Link, Lable, Text as an input, like this
[***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5NXYgzeyyA2JmH6BuxhcIBiRFRif6IXgAXY-1h1vJc/edit#gid=1635907489) of my example sheet.

```
=Function(HYPERLINK(A3,B3)," ",C3)
```

I want to create a custom Function to get the result like in `E3`
Hyperlink & Text, [`Google`](https://www.google.com/%22,%22Google) `Text`, after reading suggested answers i concluded **there is no way** to achive this result by creating a **custom formula** that can **format the output**.
the next best thing is to have a script that **extract the formula parameters** `A3`, `B3` and the tailing text and use it to output the result in the **next cell** either automatic onedit or with menu botton.

[image]

I tested [this script](https://github.com/ashtonfei/google-apps-script-projects/tree/GAS-075) but the **problem** is the formula is replaced by Plain text only, see the github project [google-apps-script-projects](https://github.com/ashtonfei/google-apps-script-projects/tree/GAS-075). or [***Make a copy***](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5NXYgzeyyA2JmH6BuxhcIBiRFRif6IXgAXY-1h1vJc/edit#gid=1635907489) of my example sheet the script is included.

Building to what [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73381745/19529694) answer, storing the parameters of the formatting in the Custom formula like this and feed it to the script to output the result in the next cell.

```
=CustomFunction([A3,B3],C3...)
```

*Explanation* 
`=CustomFunction([Hyperlink,Lable],text...)`

Comment: This is not possible with stock google functions.  It can be done with a custom function written in google AppScript though.

Comment: @MattKing [Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) can't do that.

Comment: If it is required to use the methods, which cannot be used with a custom function, with a custom function, this thread and report might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747 and https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. In the current stage, in order to reflect the hyperlink to a part of the text in a cell, it is required to use `setRichTextValue` method of Google Apps Script. Unfortunately, this method cannot be used in a custom function. So, I proposed to run the script with the methods except for custom function in that thread. But, if you are required to use this method with a custom function, there is a workaround. So, I proposed it in my previous comment in your question. I apologize for my proposal.

Comment: @Rubén The question is updated, and I visited the suggested questions and concluded that they are different to my question. Please take your time to read the question. I really need the responses, please guys vote to reopen.

Comment: Please show how you tried to use the newRichTextValue and setRichTextValue methods.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thanks for the suggestions, i understood your intrepretation perfectly what i did't foud is a simple example im new to googleAppScript , 
lets modify your example in github to do something like this `=CustomConcatenationFunction(Hyperlink(Link,Lable),"Text1","Text2"...)`  its like a super concatenation function. is it possible?

Comment: Hi @Rubén I added **`newRichTextValue`**, **`setRichTextValue`** source and implementation, you can [Make a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5NXYgzeyyA2JmH6BuxhcIBiRFRif6IXgAXY-1h1vJc/copy) of my example sheet to see the script i used, Im even ready to start a bounty if Im eligible to get more answers, thanks.

Comment: @Osm Thanks for your reply. It's better to add a [mcve], anyway, in your spreadsheet you mention that running the script removes the formula and you ask if there is a way to avoid this. The answer is no. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/64170827/1595451

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a workaround for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? But, if that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Osm Thank you for replying. From `From the question @Rubén sugested I got an idea that we can keep the formula in one cell and output the formatted text in an other cell either onchange or with a menu botton, some thing like this, extract the formula as text and feed it's values to a script and output the result text to the next cell and format it based on the custom function.`, I understood that my answer was not useful. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Osm In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I have to study more.

Comment: You answer is useful, we need a workaround to keep the formula in place eiather in a seprate cell or in the formatted cell, I understood you perfectly. we have half of the question answered the last bit is to keep the formula extract the url, lable plain text from it and output the formatted result to a cell on the right as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that my proposed workaround was not useful. I have to apologize for this. So, when I have another approach, I would like to propose it. Now, I think that in this case, the reason for this issue is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for my poor skill, again.

Comment: Just allow me a little time to cut out the unnecessary details from my question. Everything is scattered all around the place.

Comment: From `we need a workaround to keep the formula in place eiather in a seprate cell or in the formatted cell, I understood you perfectly. we have half of the question answered the last bit is to keep the formula extract the url, lable plain text from it and output the formatted result to a cell on the right as a workaround.`, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was also not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- Put a text to a cell. In this case, use a hyperlink in a part of the text.
- You are required to achieve this using a custom function like `=CustomConcatenationFunction(Hyperlink(Link,Lable),"Text1","Text2"...)`.

In the current stage, in order to reflect the hyperlink in a part of the text, it is required to use `setRichTextValue` of Google Apps Script. In this case, this method cannot be used with the custom function. This is the current specification.

And, in the case of a custom function like `=CustomConcatenationFunction(Hyperlink(Link,Lable),"Text1","Text2"...)`, the arguments at the custom function side are `label`, `"Text1"` and `"Text2"`. I think that in this case, the URL cannot be retrieved at the custom function. I think that this is also a modification point.

So, in order to achieve your goal, it is required to use a workaround. In this post, I would like to introduce the workaround. This workaround uses Web Apps. When Web Apps is used, the methods which cannot be used with a custom function can be used with a custom function. This can be seen at [this report](https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper) and [Error when running Youtube Data Service in App Scripts (js) – Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747).

When Web Apps is used for achieving your goal, it becomes as follows.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare Google Spreadsheet.

Please create a Google Spreadsheet.

#### 2. Prepare sample script.

Please open the script editor of Spreadsheet and copy and paste the following sample script.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const { range, sheetName, link, text, allText } = e.parameter;
  const idx = allText.indexOf(text);
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(allText)
    .setLinkUrl(idx, idx + text.length, link)
    .build();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getRange(range)
    .setRichTextValue(r);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}

// This is used as the custom function.
function SAMPLE(link, text, allText) {
  const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set the URL of Web Apps after you set the Web Apps.
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `${webAppsUrl}?range=${range.getA1Notation()}&sheetName=${range
      .getSheet()
      .getSheetName()}&link=${link}&text=${text}&allText=${allText}`
  );
}
```

- Here, `webAppsUrl` is required to be replaced with your Web Apps URL. Web Apps is deployed in the following flow.

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

The detailed information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Please set this using the new IDE of the script editor.

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of the Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`, and replace `webAppsUrl` in the above sample script.
8. **Reflect the latest script to the Web Appps. Because the script of Web Apps is changed. This is an important point.**

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
   - You can see the detail of this in the report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 4. Testing.

In order to test the above sample, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE("###URL###","sampleLink","sampleText sampleLink sampleText")`. By this, `sampleLink` of `sampleText sampleLink sampleText` has the hyperlink as follows.

[image]

### Note:

- In this case, the inputted custom function is overwritten by the RichTextValue. Because in the current stage, the RichTextValue cannot be used in a custom function.
- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### References:

- [Enhanced Custom Function for Google Spreadsheet using Web Apps as Wrapper](https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper).
- This sample is for [this thread in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73367517/7108653)

### Added:

From `we need a workaround to keep the formula in place eiather in a seprate cell or in the formatted cell, I understood you perfectly. we have half of the question answered the last bit is to keep the formula extract the url, lable plain text from it and output the formatted result to a cell on the right as a workaround.`, how about the following sample script?

In this sample script, the simple trigger of OnEdit is used.

#### Sample script:

```js
const SAMPLE = _ => "Done";

function onEdit(e) {
  const customFunction = "=SAMPLE";
  const { range } = e;
  const formula = range.getFormula();
  if (!formula.includes(customFunction)) return;
  const arguments = formula.match(/\((.+)\)/);
  if (!arguments) return;
  const [link, text, allText] = arguments[1].replace(/"/g, "").split(",");
  const idx = allText.indexOf(text);
  const r = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(allText).setLinkUrl(idx, idx + text.length, link).build();
  range.offset(0, 1).setRichTextValue(r);
}
```

- When you use this script, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("###URL###","sampleLink","sampleText sampleLink sampleText")` to a cell. By this, the script of `onEdit` is automatically run by the trigger.

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tanaike thanks for your response, From the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170827/how-to-set-part-of-string-bold) @Rubén sugested I got an idea that we can keep the formula in one cell and output the formatted text in an other cell either onchange or with a menu botton, some thing like this, extract the formula as text and feed it's values to a script and output the result text to the next cell and format it based on the custom function.

Comment: I apologize; I will soon make my question simpler.

Comment: @Osm Thank you for replying. From `From the question @Rubén sugested I got an idea that we can keep the formula in one cell and output the formatted text in an other cell either onchange or with a menu botton, some thing like this, extract the formula as text and feed it's values to a script and output the result text to the next cell and format it based on the custom function.`, I understood that my answer was not useful. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Osm In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I have to study more.

Comment: @Osm Thank you for replying. When you tested it and that was not useful, I apologize again.